# Error Handling - Email SendLog

Tags: marketing-cloud, triggered-send

I'm investigating a delta between records processed by our system calling MC Rest API and the actual number of emails sent by MC.

I'm looking into the Email SendLog which I already enhanced with an number of fields like emailname etc.

The issue is that for a failed send you don't get a JobID or anything, except for the TriggeredSendID, which seems to be different depending on whether the send succeeded or not.

So I'm wondering, what is this TriggeredSendID and how can I use it to determine for which email the Send failed (I can't use SendDate to determine which email it was by the way.)

Answer (score 1):

If you hover over a Triggered Send in the Interactions tab, you will see something like 
https://members.s10.exacttarget.com/Content/Interactions/TriggeredSendConfiguration.aspx?CategoryID=8933&ts=a3587f7f-a74c-e911-a2d4-1402ec8ca79d&smtp=1&tsc=1  appearing in a small yellow frame at the bottom of your browser window.

This part is the TriggeredSendID that appears for the send in the SendLog: a3587f7f-a74c-e911-a2d4-1402ec8ca79d

(so everything between the ts= and &smtp parameter functions)

Answering question myself because I stumbled upon the solution in the UI today.